# expand, factor and simplify on Octave

Tags: octave

What are the equivalent commands to expand, factor and simplify on Octave?

example:

```
expand((x+1)^2);
x^2+2x+1

simplify(3*x^2+2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think the real problem is that Octave is not ment to support much of symbolic math as Wolfram Mathematica etc does. The best way would be:
1. Rethink your problem. Is there really a inevitable need for these functions? (And is it necessary to solve it using Octave?)
2. If your problem is about polynomes only (as your example would suggest), work just with vectors containing its coefficients. For this kind of purposes Octave actually has some functions, see: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Polynomial-Manipulations.html

Answer (score 1):

You may check this out: http://octave.sourceforge.net/symbolic/index.html . It seems like having expand only.